# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_*%$^&'

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table with Primary key 'ID' that auto increments every time a new entry(row) comes in. The max(ID) is now 18. Now I want to insert a new row between 17 and 18 and also rename the IDs accordingly like 18 becomes 19 and the new row has to be 18 as below. I know I'll get a Primary Key Violation error, Is it possible to do this any other way ?

```
ID---------COLUMNS-----------

17---------OLD ROW-----------
18---------NEW ROW----------- 
19---------OLD ROW-----------
```

Comment: No, you don't want to do that. Primary key has nothing to do with row order. So if you really need consecutive, add the corresponding column, but leave primary key routines to DBMS

Comment: In a relational database rows have no order, so there is no such thing as inserting a row "between" two other rows. Ordering is applied only when querying your data using an ORDER BY clause. If you need to include some ordering in your data then you will need to add another column which you can populate as you like.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments an id is just an identifier. It's order (and even value, provided it's unique) doesn't matter.

If you absolutely must do this you'll need to change the id of the first column before inserting:

```
UPDATE table SET ID = 19 WHERE ID = 18;
INSERT INTO table (id,foo) VALUES (18,'foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

While Alma Do is correct in saying that your design is flawed if you rely on an auto-generated index as a sorting order, you can work around the uniqueness constraint by first incrementing your values in descending order (so that there never are two records with the same value):

```
UPDATE yourtable SET id = id+1 WHERE id >= 18
ORDER BY id DESC; -- here is the trick
```